# Angular UI Router 1.0 - why $scope.$watch('$destroy') is called without leaving state?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Check the plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/HclyeeDmJKrXSnlweDsS?p=preview).

As far as I know, `$scope.$watch('$destroy')` should be called when $scope is about to be destroyed.

The example above shows that when entering into a state, it's `$scope.$watch('$destroy')` is called right away. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
$scope.$watch('$destroy', ...
```

We should use

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', ...
```

Comment: If that helped, great... those small things could consume so much time ;) Good luck with UI-Router, sir